# How to pull value from cookie with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Say my web server is using the foobar=12345; cookie amongst several others. How can I use JavaScript to extract and store the value of the foobar cookie within a JavaScript parameter where it can then be parsed to other functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use js-cookie. See https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie

If you are using a bundler with npm, run: `npm i js-cookie`

Or, use JSDelivr:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/js-cookie@rc/dist/js.cookie.min.js"></script>
```

Then, it is as easy as this:

```
Cookies.get("foobar")
```

If you don't want to use js-cookie, see: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp